# How to plot picture with a colored segmentation and alpha channel?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I want to plot a segmentation with its a picture with a certain alpha channel. I got my segmentation in red, but when I superpose the two pictures, the white part impacts my picture. How to consider the segmented part?

[image]

Comment: Please post your images separately so others can use them to demonstrate the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`skimage.color.label2rgb`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.label2rgb), specifying the `bg_label`. The parts where the segmentation equals `bg_label` will be transparent. You can see example usages of the function linked at the end of the function documentation.